# Not responding to ARP w/ request for IP 0.0.0.0

Tags: arp

I'm working on a personal project that involves ARP requests to a **specific/known** MAC for IP 0.0.0.0: `Who has 0.0.0.0? Tell x.x.x.x`. As far as I'm aware ***any*** receiving host should respond to that, but it seems certain OSes (*nix flavours in particular) don't quite adhere. My Android-based phone responds just fine, but none of my OS X/Debian boxes do. They do respond when I ask them specifically about their own IP, so it's not that they disregard unicast requests entirely. I've yet to test Windows.

Any known reason why that is and/or how to fix/work around that? Basically I need to probe a host on my LAN by MAC address and check if it's still around (i.e. responds to the probe). If there's a better way besides ARP to do this I'll take any suggestions, but without sending requests for all possible IPs on the LAN to the specific MAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as a separate answer so I can accept it. =]

I ended up changing the whole ARP thing to use ICMP instead, since apparently the `Who has 0.0.0.0?` is illegal after all.

My program now sends an ICMP echo request (ping) packet with IP destination `224.0.0.1` (layer 3, multicast to all hosts), **but** it sets the destination MAC (layer 2) to the specific ones I'm monitoring. It does incur noticeable overhead now, but I guess I'll just have to live with that.